# Passing reactive data to global environment

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I want to use Shiny within RMarkdown for users to upload data (xlsx file).
 Then I want to pass all the worksheets as R data frames (w/o reactivity) to run rest of the RMarkdown file.
I mainly want to convert them into data frames so I can use `reticulate` to run Python code as well.

I've tried this, and it doesn't seem to quite work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(miniUI)
library(shiny)
library(XLConnect)

launch_shiny <- function() {

  ui <- miniPage(
    gadgetTitleBar("Input Data"),
    miniContentPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = "my.file", label = NULL, multiple = FALSE)
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    wb <- reactive({
      new.file <- input$my.file
      loadWorkbook(
        filename = new.file$datapath,
        create = FALSE,
        password = NULL
      )
    })

    observeEvent(input$done, {
      stopApp(c(wb()))
    })

  }
  runGadget(ui, server)

}

test <- launch_shiny()
df1 <- readWorksheet(object = test, sheet = "sheet1")
df2 <- readWorksheet(object = test, sheet = "sheet2")
```

It throws this error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readWorksheet’ for signature ‘"list", "character"’
```

I can return one sheet at a time using `stopApp(readWorksheet(object = wb(), sheet = "sheet1"))`, but I can't seem to return an entire workbook or multiple data frames at the same time.

I don't really want to read in xlsx, save each sheet as csv in working directory, then read those files in again.
Would anyone have a good suggestion on how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `fileInput()` states in the details:

> datapath
>
> The path to a temp file that contains the data that was
>   uploaded. This file may be deleted if the user performs another upload
>   operation.

Meaning that the `datapath` given in the input variable is a temporary file that is  no longer accessible after you close the App, which is what the function `readWorksheet` will try to do.

So you'll have to read the sheets in the server and return the dataframes somehow.
I did that by defining a second reactive value which is basically a list of dataframes returned by applying `lapply` on all the sheets in `wb`, in this case `test` will be this list of data frames.

There might be other ways (more efficient, or suits your purpose better) to do this, but here it is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(miniUI)
library(shiny)
library(XLConnect)

launch_shiny <- function() {

  ui <- miniPage(
    gadgetTitleBar("Input Data"),
    miniContentPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = "my.file", label = NULL, 
                multiple = FALSE)
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    wb <- reactive({
      new.file <- input$my.file
      loadWorkbook(
        filename = new.file$datapath,
        create = FALSE,
        password = NULL
      )
    })

    # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    df_lst <- reactive({
      # read all sheets into a list
      lapply(getSheets(wb()), 
             function(sheet){
               readWorksheet(object = wb(), 
                             sheet = sheet)
             })
    })
   # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    observeEvent(input$done, {
      # get the list of dfs from the app
      stopApp(c(df_lst())) 
    })

  }
  runGadget(ui, server)
  }

test <- launch_shiny()
```

Comment: CLEVER! I should have thought about returning a list, I was so hung up on data frames. This is great, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help! :)